# How do I make an authorized fetch request from a static Firebase hosted site to a Google Cloud Run service?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, authorization, google-cloud-run

I have a an Express server on a Google Could Run service. The same project also has a Firebase hosted static site. The Google Cloud Run service only allows authenticated requests  (it is not a public api).

Requests from the front end work when the Cloud Run service is set to allow unauthenticated traffic. I am not using custom domains on the cloud run service or the firebase service.

I have tried to follow these [Authenticating Service to Service](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/service-to-service) directions, but it seems that direction to use the Google Auth library pertains to back end code, but my request is from the client. Another method listed in addition to using an authentication library is to use the metadata server, but this also works only

So far, I have:

1. Created a service account in IAM & Admin: fb-cloud-run-invoker@express-cloudrun.iam.gserviceaccount.com
2. I gave this service Cloud Run Invoker role
3. I added my firebase-adminsdk... service as a principal on this fb-cloud-run-invoker service (although I'm not sure this is necessary)

On Cloud Run, I see that fb-cloud-run-invoker@express-cloudrun.iam.gserviceaccount.com is a principal listed under permissions.

Now, according to the documentation, I am to fetch a Google-signed ID token and then I can use that token in the header of my fetch requests to make authorized requests to my cloud run service.

This is where I am stuck. It seems this process of fetching the ID token has to happen on the server. My firebase site is only the static files. I understand I would not be able to hide any secrets in my front end code so that makes sense. So, then how am I going to make an authorized fetch request from my firebase site (client) to my cloud run service (express server)?

I want to make authorized fetch requests from a Firebase static site to a Cloud Run service api (using express). I get a 403 error in response when I attempt to fetch from the Cloud Run Api.

Comment: As you noted, those instructions are labeled "Authenticating Service to Service" but you're trying to use it for client to service authentication. What sort of requests are you trying to use authentication to prevent? You may be better off allowing unauthenticated invocations to Cloud Run and using a different authentication solution.